# How to display similar rows once for SQL left join on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following table in my postgresql database:

```
id|user_id|document_id|
--|-------|-----------|
 1|10     |        100|
 2|20     |        100|
 3|10     |        200|
 4|20     |        200|
 5|10     |        300|
 6|20     |        300|
 7|10     |        400|
 8|20     |        400|
```

I now join this table with itself on the column document_id as follows:

```
select t1.document_id, t1.user_id as user_id1, t2.user_id as user_id2
from test_table t1 left join test_table t2 on (t1.document_id = t2.document_id and t1.user_id <> t2.user_id);
```

The result:

```
document_id|user_id1|user_id2|
-----------|--------|--------|
        100|10      |20      |
        100|20      |10      |
        200|10      |20      |
        200|20      |10      |
        300|10      |20      |
        300|20      |10      |
        400|10      |20      |
        400|20      |10      |
```

Here I want to remove similar rows such as the one below because both records mean the same thing:

```
document_id|user_id1|user_id2|
-----------|--------|--------|
        100|10      |20      |
        100|20      |10      |
```

So, the expected result should look like:

```
document_id|user_id1|user_id2|
-----------|--------|--------|
        100|10      |20      |
        200|10      |20      |
        300|10      |20      |
        400|10      |20      |
```

So I basically require document_id to appear once rather than twice. Is there any way to do so?

Edit:

I tried the following query as suggested by @jarlh:

```
select t1.document_id, t1.user_id as user_id1, t2.user_id as user_id2
from test_table t1 left join test_table t2 on (t1.document_id = t2.document_id and t1.user_id < t2.user_id);
```

But the result is that user_id2 is null when user_id1 is greater of the two:

```
document_id|user_id1|user_id2|
-----------|--------|--------|
        100|10      |20      |
        100|20      |        |
        200|10      |20      |
        200|20      |        |
        300|10      |20      |
        300|20      |        |
```

Comment: Do `user_id1 < user_id2` instead.

Comment: Ok, I tried that but now I get a null value for user_id2 where user_id1 is the greater of the two.

Edit: Updated the OP with output.

Comment: I didn't notice the LEFT JOIN. Simply try a regular INNER JOIN.

Comment: BTW, maybe you should add the rows (7,10,400) and (8, 20, 100) to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Oh yeah, silly me. Makes sense that it would be null now. I used left join because this is actually a subset of a larger table and I needed left join to track some non-matching values.

Comment: >BTW, maybe you should add the rows (7,10,400) and (8, 20, 100) to the sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly.

I don't see the point, but I added those rows.

Comment: Having a row with a unique document_id makes the problem different, also having the same document_id 3 times. (E.g. (8, 20, **100**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @jarlh might be one way to go here, but another way would be to select distinct using least/greatest:

```
select distinct
    t1.document_id,
    least(t1.user_id, t2.user_id) as user_id1,
    greatest(t1.user_id, t2.user_id) as user_id2
from test_table t1
left join test_table t2
    on t1.document_id = t2.document_id and
       t1.user_id <> t2.user_id;
```